# pe:documentViewer not working if name attribute is used

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I use primefaces extensions `documentViewer` to display pdfs:

```
<pe:documentViewer id="docViewerId" value="#{contentBL.inlineContent}" name="#{contentBL.getContentDataName()}" />
```

This works so far until I give the attribute name a value like in the code above. Then the viewer does not show the pdf with a message:

PDF.js Version 1.0.21 (build: f954cde)
Nachricht: InvalidPDFException

I want to define the name of the file if the pdf is downloaded.

I am using PF extensions 3.2.0.

Comment: It is always good to create an [mcve] and to provide version info (see [ask]) Do you use `StreamedContend`? If so, check its [API](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.2/org/primefaces/model/StreamedContent.html). It has a setName(...), so I expect the name attribute is not needed then and might even conflict. BTW, I never used this component, I just inspected docs to find a possible cause. Easy to do yourself

Comment: Yes it is streamed content and the name is already set. But if I download the pdf in the viewer the default name is just "document.pdf" which was not the name I set.

Comment: Why did you omit all this info from the Q? Again…  Create an mcve…

Comment: I think a mcve wouldn't be helpful. It work as long I do not give the attribute `name` a value. Sounds like a but. Even if I set `name="blabla.pdf"` it crashes.

Comment: Good luck then… I'm not going to try to replicate without an [mcve]. Nor am I going to create something from scratch to try to make it work